# Not requiring users to confirm email with Devise

Tags: email, devise, confirm

I'm using Devise in a Rails 3 (3.0.5) project. I want to use the confirmable module to allow users to confirm their email address, however I don't want to block them if they do not confirm.

I have currently done this by setting (in devise.rb)

```
config.confirm_within = 100.years
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

actually in newer versions of devise its

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 100.years
```

And in my opinion it's an alright solution

Answer (score 3):

You can now set config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for to nil to allow unconfirmed logins indefinitely whilst still requesting confirmation.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2278
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L142

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, but I really have to ask why you are using the confirmable module if you are just gonna let them in anyway? What value does the confirmation module bring if you let people slip by?

You might as well say `user.confirm!` within the create action so you don't have to set a value of `100.years`

Comment: It's just the business logic required for this project: Don't block users who don't confirm, instead offer them incentives to confirm.